# SQL query, am I wrong somewhere?

Tags: sql

I am trying to pull distinct `City` names and only one zipcode for any given City.

```
zip city    state
00603   AGUADILLA   PR
00604   AGUADILLA   PR
00605   AGUADILLA   PR
```

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (city),(zip) 
  FROM zips 
 WHERE state = 'PR'
```

I tried group by clause as well, let me know where am I wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select city, max(zip)
from zips
where state='PR'
group by city
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT city, max(zip) from zips where state='PR' group by city, state
```